# How to make a function run for specific seconds without sleep

Tags: python-3.x

Consider the below code:

```
def boil():
    print("Boiling")

def cool():
    print("Cooling")
    sleep(2)

start = time.time()   
boil()
cool()
boil()
cool()
print(round(time.time()-start)," secs")
```

I want the boil() function to run for 3 seconds without using sleep() so that the final output is 10 secs. How can I do this?

Note: I am creating two set of codes for illustrating sequential and concurrent. Hence I dont want to have sleep() in the boil() as it would make it concurrent when I use threads as below so that the code can execute 2 secs faster:

```
def boil():
    print("Boiling")

def cool():
    print("Cooling")
    sleep(2)

start = time.time()   
boil()
#Here I am cooling and cooking concurrently
Thread(target=cool).start()
boil()
cool()
print(round(time.time()-start)," secs")
```

Comment: Well, sleep() puts the thread in waiting state and I dont want that in the boil(). This is a simplified version of  the problem I trying to solve.

Comment: If you use threads, you should show some threading code and explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: sigh. See, I am trying to create two different set of codes. One to illustrate  sequential programming and the other to illustrate concurrent programming. Having a sleep() in my boil() would defeat the purpose. The current code is meant to illustrate sequential. Later I will be modifying the code using threads to illustrate concurrent programming.

Comment: Why not add this information to the question? Along with an example that makes clear what you are up to.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try something like this. Using `time.clock()` instead

```
import time

def boil():
    print("Boiling")
    b_start = time.clock()
    b_end = time.clock()
    while b_end - b_start < 3: # 3 second delay
        b_end = time.clock()

def cool():
    print("Cooling")
    time.sleep(2)


start = time.clock()
end = time.clock()

while end - start < 10: # runs for 10 seconds
    boil()
    cool()
    end = time.clock()

print(round(time.clock()-start)," secs")

#Output
Boiling
Cooling
Boiling
Cooling
10  secs
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want sleep() on the cool(), as I mentioned I will be using threads later on.

Comment: I thought you said without sleep? I assumed the use of sleep in your example was what you wanted to change.

Comment: Oh my! Sorry for the lack of clarity in the question. The boil() should not have sleep() whereas the cool() should have it. That way I can use it to illustrate sequential and concurrent programming.

Comment: Okay, fixed answer now.

Comment: The boil() and cool() were called 3 times and the code ran for 15 secs totally

Comment: Added output. That's exactly what I get just running the code provided

Comment: Is it because of the reason that I am using windows? Thanks for the direction. I will see how I can modify this for windows.